# Error trying to use a WCF Data Service (.net 4 EF?) in a Windows Forms app (.net 4.5 EF5)

Tags: winforms, wcf, entity-framework

Not sure why it is looking for Entity Framework, and can't find it. Completely blanking on what to do.

[image: Could not load file or assembly]

In the Windows Forms application the `app.config` has this

```
<section name="entityFramework" 
         type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

my `web.config` contains

```
<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</assemblies>
```

Form1:

```
  public Form1 (): base()
  {
  InitializeComponent();
  MAXFMWebEntities context = new MAXFMWebEntities();
  }
```

Comment: And what is Form1 doing?

Comment: Sorry... updated example

Comment: Ok, I don't see anything in there relating to WCF.

Comment: Now we're going to ask how MAXFMWebEntities is defined, and then you'll show that, and then we'll ask how your configuration is, and then you'll show that, and we'll keep asking you questions that you should have supplied originally in your question.. so why not just supply as much information now as you can?  It would really speed things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated app.config
suggested in [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Data.OData Version=5.2.0.0 error in Azure Cloud Worker Role using Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908384/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-odata-version-5-2-0-0-error-in-az)

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.4.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```