# How to use two dlls in an application which reference different versions of same dll?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dll

I have an application which uses "Windows Azure Storage 2.1.0.2" and "WCF Data Services Client5.6.0". First library depends on Microsoft.Data.OData 5.2.0 and second library depends on Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AssemblyBinding redirection to redirect the older version to the newer version.  See [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Data.OData Version=5.2.0.0 error in Azure Cloud Worker Role using Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908384/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-odata-version-5-2-0-0-error-in-az) for the same question.

Here is the short answer:

```
 <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: @kwill can we include a condition to check if a perticular version of software installed then bind specif assembly