# Missed some reference from my asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, reference, assemblies, odata

When I try to run my asp.net application, it gives me this error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I think I miss some assembly reference but I can't get which one is?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: `Install-Package Microsoft.Data.OData` in the package console?

Comment: @EricHotinger now getting this error
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: That seems to match what I suggested below. This may have something to do with the new web.config entry. Are you using MVC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related: [Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Data.OData Version=5.2.0.0 error in Azure Cloud Worker Role using Table Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908384/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-data-odata-version-5-2-0-0-error-in-az)

Try adding this to your web.config:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```